# how to delete the sample that don't have data for the whole period?

Tags: excel, pandas

I have a dataset that looks like this.

```
sample     day
1          -10
1          -9
.           .
.           .
.           .
1          10
2         -10
3         -10
.           .
.           .
.           .
3          10
```

I want only the sample with whole period from -10 to 10. In this case the sample 2 must be deleted. But the missing period for each sample is different some go from -10 to 0, some -10 to -8 (number of rows for each sample is varied). How should I write in pandas or excel to delete incomplete samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you need to use a boolean expression, if the period is alwas -10 to 10 then the sum of these numbers should always be `0`

```
print(df)

   sample  day
0       1  -10
0       1   -9
0       1   -8
0       1   -7
0       1   -6
0       1   -5
0       1   -4
0       1   -3
0       1   10
.......
1       2    4
1       2    5

df1 = df[df.groupby(['sample'])['day'].transform('sum').eq(0)]

print(df1)

   sample  day
0       1  -10
0       1   -9
0       1   -8
0       1   -7
0       1   -6
0       1   -5
0       1   -4
0       1   -3
0       1   -2
0       1   -1
0       1    0
0       1    1
0       1    2
0       1    3
0       1    4
0       1    5
0       1    6
0       1    7
0       1    8
0       1    9
0       1   10
```

Comment: The result is exactly what I want. Your single line of code has made my day. Thank a lot!

Comment: @Soda happy to help my friend